# import discord gives me an error on repl.it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

I'm trying to host a bot on repl.it, and when I was trying to run the bot this error message was shown:

```
File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

This seemed weird to me as my code worked perfectly fine last time I tried to run it.
I did some further investigating and found that discord.py has a dependency called `aiohttp`, so I tried to install the package myself, and then this happened:

```
Using version ^3.8.1 for aiohttp

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

  SolverProblemError

  Because discord.py (1.7.3) depends on aiohttp (>=3.6.0,<3.8.0)
   and no versions of discord.py match >1.7.3,<2.0.0, discord.py (>=1.7.3,<2.0.0) requires aiohttp (>=3.6.0,<3.8.0).
  So, because basically-another-discordpy-bot depends on both discord.py (^1.7.3) and aiohttp (^3.8.1), version solving failed.

  at /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
      242│ 
      243│         results = dict(
      244│             depth_first_search(
      245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes
exit status 1


Replit: Package operation failed.
```

What is happening here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you run your code on your local machine it always have the same configuration (it keeps all your files, installed dependencies, etc.), but on repl.it it works differently. Some of them might be missing.

### Fixing your error:

Open your file in repl.it and on your left click **"packages"** icon and search for `discord`. Click "+" to install the package. Now it should install every time you run your code.

[image: screenshot]

---

An alternative method is to make a `requirements.txt` file and write `discord.py` inside it. Then at the top of your code add this to install required dependencies every time you run your script:

```py
import os
os.system("python -m pip install -r requirements.txt")
```

Comment: This worked but it just made me even more confused because I already have discord.py installed (I explicitly checked it) before running the code. Maybe making that requirements.txt file is mandatory? But doesn't it just install the package again?