# discord giving packaging error on replit. anyone know what todo?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is the console output I got when attempting to run the bot. It's supposed to install discord.py but it doesn't and I can't figure out why.

```
Replit: Updating package configuration

--> python3 -m poetry add discord pytz requests
Using version ^1.7.3 for discord
Using version ^2022.1 for pytz
Using version ^2.28.0 for requests

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

   SolverProblemError

   Because no versions of discord match >1.7.3,<2.0.0
    and discord (1.7.3) depends on aiohttp (>=1.7.3), discord (>=1.7.3,<2.0.0) requires discord.py (>=1.7.3).
   Because discord.py (1.7.3) depends on aiohttp (>=3.6.0,<3.8.0)
    and no versions of discord.py match >1.7.3, discord.py (>=1.7.3) requires aiohttp (>=3.6.0,<3.8.0).
   Thus, discord (>=1.7.3,<2.0.0) requires aiohttp (>=3.6.0,<3.8.0).
   So, because python-template depends on both aiohttp (^3.8.1) and discord (^1.7.3), version solving failed.

   at venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/puzzel/solver.py:241 in _solve
       237|             packages = result.packages
       238|         except OverrideNeeded as e:
       239|             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
       240|         except SolveFailure as e:
       241|             raise SolverProblemError(e)
       242|
       243|         results = dict(
       244|             depth_first_search(
       245|                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes
/home/runner/FWT-TESTER/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptooolsDeprecationWarning: Setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
exit status 1


replit: Package operation failed.
```

Comment: Have you tried installing with `pip` instead of `poetry`? Multiple repl.it threads appear to implicate the latter as the problem.

Comment: I have tried pip, it has the same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import discord gives me an error on repl.it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70730968/import-discord-gives-me-an-error-on-repl-it)

Comment: tried, and it doesnt work from my testing..

Answer (score 2):

if your wanna install the latest version or development version of `discord.py`, do

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

Note that git must be available at $PATH

Also don't try to install discord py using poetry because it's unstable to install from there